# How to list/create a domain using designateclient?

Tags: python, rest, openstack

I've been trying to use the designate client to create DNS entries, but even before creating them, I tried listing all the entries.

Started with listing zones first and it doesn't seem to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import json
from designateclient.v2 import client
from keystoneauth1.identity import generic
from keystoneauth1 import session as keystone_session

auth = generic.Password(
    auth_url='url',
    username='username',
    password=os.environ['password'],
    project_name='domain name',
    project_domain_id='default',
    user_domain_id='default')


session = keystone_session.Session(auth=auth)

client = client.Client(session=session)

print(client.zones.list())
```

Any help how I could get this data? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

So I got over the issue of authentication, by using the following code:

```
import os
from keystoneclient.auth.identity import v3
from keystoneclient import session
from keystoneclient.v3 import client
from designateclient.v2 import client as d_client

v3_auth = v3.Password(auth_url='auth_url',
                      username='username',
                      password=os.environ['pass'],
                      project_name='project_name',
                      project_domain_name="project_domain_name",
                      user_domain_name="user_domain_name")

v3_ses = session.Session(auth=v3_auth)
auth_token = v3_ses.get_token()

session = session.Session(auth=v3_auth, timeout=10)

desig_client = d_client.Client(session=session)
print(desig_client)

list_of_zones = desig_client.zones.list()
```

The next question is how do I create a new domain?